# calculate specific td and display in the other td

Tags: jquery, html

I want to calculate specific `td` and `display` in the other `td`. However, it only shows NaN... can someone help to fix it?

```
<table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td class="v2">29</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="v1" class="v1" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td class="result"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    $(function(){
    $("#v1").on("keyup", function() {
        $('.table1 tr').each(function(i){
        var sum = parseFloat($(this).find('.v2').text()) - parseFloat($(this).find('.v1').val());
            $(this).find('.result').text(sum);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: the another tr showing this NaN. No need to iterate the tr. Or You can do the same by using sibling of the td in same tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, You just find out exactly each element that you need to get the value.

Check my demo below to have better understand.

```js
$("#v1").on("keyup", function() {
    var numberV2 = parseFloat($(".v2").text());
    var numberV1 = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('.result').html(numberV2 - numberV1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td class="v2">29</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="v1" class="v1" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td class="result"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to iterate on every TR element

```js
$(function(){

$("#v1").on("keyup", function() {
 sum = parseFloat($('.v2').text()) - parseFloat($('.v1').val());
    $('.result').text(sum);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td class="v2">29</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="v1" class="v1" type="text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td class="result"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```